# Get the state of the file(in work, pending, synced)

Tags: perforce

Is there a direct command that can compare the workspace file with the depot file and return the state of the file?

e.g.

`p4 fstat D:/path/my_file.txt` => `inwork`

`p4 fstat D:/path/my_file.txt` => `up-to-date`

Comment: What's the difference between "in work" and "pending"?  They both sound like ways to describe the state of a file being "opened" in Perforce (which the "p4 opened" command will show you, as will "p4 fstat")..

Comment: Something else to consider is that a file can be any combination of both/either "opened" (inwork) and "synced" (up-to-date) -- it's not necessarily obvious how to reduce all the information "p4 fstat" gives you to a single line of description, which is why "fstat" doesn't do that.

Comment: @SamStafford Maybe my explanation was not suggestive enough. What I  mean by `state` is to know whether a file from my workspace( let's assume that now it has version `1.5`) was changed or it has the same content with the version `1.5` version of the file from depot.

Comment: Ah!  That's just `p4 diff -f`.

Comment: @SamStafford Thank you kindly for your time and for your patience, `p4 diff -f file_path` returns `file_path - file(s) not on client` and `p4 diff file_path` returns `file_path - file(s) not opened on this client`.

Comment: That means that no version of the file was synced to your workspace (you just said you had version "1.5", but what that output is saying is that you have version #0).  The workflow should be: 1. `p4 sync file_path` 2. `p4 edit file_path` 3. modify file 4. `p4 submit`.  If you're copying the file in from somewhere else something is wrong.

Comment: @SamStafford You were right, sorry. I checked and I was looking at some generated files. Please post a new answer or edit your current one so I can accept it. The command is working as expected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to the rephrased question:

> Is there a direct command that can compare the workspace file with the
>   depot file and return the state of the file?

`p4 diff -f [filename]` will force a comparison (diff) regardless of whether the file is open.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear since you don't define what exactly you mean by "state" -- the `p4 fstat` command returns a lot of information about a file's state, and it sounds like you want some subset of that but you don't specify what.

That said, I'm guessing that you might like the `p4 status` command.

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_status.html

This will tell you about files that are currently open as well as files that have been modified without being opened.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the `-s` flag to `p4 diff`, which I always mnemonically remember as the 'summary' flag.

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r17.1/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_diff.html

For example, `p4 diff -sa`: Show only the names of opened files that are different from the revision in the depot, or are missing.

Comment: This command works only from the opened Perforce client. What I want is to run the command from command line and return the state of any file, regardeless if it was opened or not in the Perforce client.